# Using JSON.NET to serialize the following JSON data

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm really struggling with serializing some JSON data, the end result needs to look like this:

```
{ 
    "jsonrpc":"2.0",
    "method":"user.authenticate",
    "params":{
        "user":"<login>",
        "password":"<password>"
    },
    "id":2
}
```

I'm trying to make use of JSON.NET, i'm passing the data in via a method but i just can't get my head around it. Any idea's on how i can get started?

thanks

Comment: "via a method"??  You want to share which method you're using?  What problems you're running into?  What you've tried, and how you failed?  Voting to close.

Comment: thanks for your contribution...

Answer (score 3):

There may well be better ways of doing it, but this seems to work:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string json = ConvertToJson("jon", "secret");
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }

    static string ConvertToJson(string login, string password)
    {
        JObject container = new JObject();
        container["jsonrpc"] = "2.0";
        container["method"] = "user.authenticate";
        container["id"] = 2;

        JObject p = new JObject();
        p["user"] = login;
        p["password"] = password;
        container["params"] = p;
        return container.ToString();
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, code is looking good and certainly explains it.  I'm looking to pass an array within the method instead of login and password as there might be times when the method variable and params contain other data. ie, it might not be username/password